# What is the appropriate word in "He [slides/puts] a ring"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

What is the appropriate word for this situation:

> He **slides** a ring on my finger

or

> He **puts** a ring on my finger.

***?***

I can't obviously say:

> He made me wear a ring.

that would mean *I myself wore it by being compelled with him*, and that's not what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both verbs work well.  "Slides" is a little more expressive. It perhaps suggests a gentle act. "Puts" is rather more neutral

> He looked into my eyes and, sliding the ring onto my finger, whispered "I'll always love you".
>
> He put the magic ring on my finger and suddenly I could see the invisible dragon that was standing behind him.